# Remove encryption from files on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption

I m using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit and few months back it crashed for the unknown reasons...I tried to recover that problem through repairing up from the original DVD but nothing was useful so I re-installed the windows copy and now I'm can't open my encrypted files...please help as I've encrypted very important files like official ones and some family pics.
I tried everything in UAC too but failed to reach to any solution.

Comment: What kind of encryption were you using?  Bitlocker?  NFTS encryption?  PGP?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's most likely way past when you cared about the answer, but in the long shot that the answer I found after stumbling onto your post does help someone else, what I realized was that the new Windows needed the Encryption Key Backup File, ".pfx". If you made a backup of the key, then you can get into the files, otherwise: tuff stuff: that's the whole point of encrypting your files, so someone without the key wouldn't be able to easily get into your files, except for the usual brute force guessing.

Good luck!